# Returning min on a stream determined by object outside of Stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, min, comparator

I'm looking for a `Comparator` to write to put inside a `min` in a `stream` on a collection, let's just say it's a `List<Node>` . Normally I'd just compare the objects of the List against one another, but my issue is I have a `<Node>` which is outside of the collection, and I need to return the minimum value of the Nodes within the collection, as they are pitted against the parent node.

I have an object of `Node`

```
public class Node {
  private int cost;
  private int location;
  public int getCost() { return cost }
}
```

I compare the nodes in the collection against the parent node with an outside function:

`public int distanceBetween(Node parent, Node child) { ... }`

And now I want to basically write a stream operation that returns the Node with the lowest value as it compares to its parent `Node` but that won't be in the set. Something like:

```
private Node returnOpenNodeWithLowestFCost(Node parent) {
      return nodeList.stream()
                     .min( (n1 , n2) -> ???);
                     .getOrElse(parent); 
  }
```

`nodeList` does not contain `parent`, and is a `List<Node>`

In the area containing the ??? is where I would send each N out for evaluation against its parent. So, if calling

`distanceBetween(parent, n1) > distanceBetween(parent, n2)` , it would result in n1 being returned . But I can't quite configure the function correctly. Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parent node (the one which is not contained in the list) seems to be *fixed*. This establishes an origin from which to measure the distance to the nodes of the list. If I understand correctly, you want to return the node of the list which is nearest this parent node.

For this, you'd need to get the distances of nodes `n1` and `n2` to the parent node, and compare these actual distances each other. You should return a negative value if `n1` is closer to the parent node than `n2`, `0` if both `n1` and `n2` are equally far away from the parent node, and a positive value if `n2` is closer to the parent node than `n1`. Here is a method with that logic:

```
private int compareDistances(Node n1, Node n2) {
    int distance1 = this.distanceBetween(parent, n1);
    int distance2 = this.distanceBetween(parent, n2);

    return distance2 - distance1; // negative if n1 closer than n2
}
```

And here's the comparator that uses the method above:

```
return nodeList.stream()
    .min(this::compareDistances)
    .getOrElse(parent);
```

Note: if you wanted exactly the opposite (to return the node that is farthest the parent node instead of the one that is nearest the parent node), you should use `max` instead of `min`:

```
return nodeList.stream()
    .max(this::compareDistances)
    .getOrElse(parent);
```

Comment: Thank you. Both so far are correct, but I pick yours for the clarity of your response. Follow up question, what happens if my `nodeList` only contains 1 item, will the `min()` method have a problem if it's expecting to always compare at least 2 different values in `nodeList`?

Comment: @NateH06 No problem with that, you only provide the logic to compare two elements each other, but your code actually doesn't perform any comparison. The special case you are referring to is correctly handled there, by code I suppose is in the stream implementation classes.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Comparator.comparingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) to make the comparator:

```
Comparator<Node> byDistFromParent = Comparator.comparingInt(n -> distanceBetween(parent, n));
```

It is customary to use static import of `comparingInt`, so you stream expression becomes:

```
return nodeList.stream()
          .min(comparingInt(n -> distanceBetween(parent, n));
          .orElse(parent);
```